# Will escaped JSON in html attribute cause issues?

Tags: html, json

We are inserting json into our meta tags (see below example). Right now the json keeps getting escaped instead of looking like normal json (see 2nd example). The objective is to have this meta attribute consumed by a 3rd party.

```
<meta name="foo" value="[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;,&quot;link&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/website.com\/&quot;}]">
```

Can escaped json cause issues when consumed by 3rd parties or is this a non issue?

```
<meta name="foo" value='[{"name":"xyz","link":"https:\/\/website.com\/"}]'>
```

We output the html in PHP. We've tried to avoid the escaping by the following `htmlspeciachars( json_encode( $data ) );` but no luck.

It's hard to determine if the 3rd party wont like escaped json as that third party setup isn't complete yet. Trying to avoid issues now instead of when its setup.

Comment: What issues are you anticipating? How is the third party consuming the data?